# Ember.Select content vs contentBinding

Tags: ember.js

The docs for Ember.Select use the following:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=foo ... }}
```

However, the guide uses the following

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="foo" ... }}
```

Both work.  Which is preferred and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=foo ... }}
```

You are creating a property called `content` with the value `foo` (or the value from the property `foo`) in the View. In this case the Select. Given you are only assigning a value, nothing happens in the View if the value `foo` changes in the 'parent' context. I use this approach when  I don't need bindings. i.e. When passing a generic String

```
{{view Ember.Select message="Mi message" ... }}
```

When you use:

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="foo" ... }}
```

You are setting up a [binding](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/). It basically means that you connect one property with another. When one changes the other changes too. Specifically it means that a `content` property inside the View is created with the value from the property `foo`. Whenever the property `foo` changes in the 'parent' context the `content` property in the View will change as well. The same is true in the other direction, whenever the `content` property in the View is changed the `foo` property from the 'parent' context will be modified.

[Another](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/what-do-i-use-when/) nice resource.

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

contentBInding="foo" is old Syntax content=foo is new. Old syntax must be deprecated.

[check API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html)